# Find $f$ such that $\int f^{n}(x)dx=f^{2017}(x)+C$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, polynomials

Determine the polynomial functions $f\in \mathbb{R}[X]$, for which exists $n\in \mathbb{N},n\geq 1$, so that $f^{2017}$ is an antiderivative for $f^n$.

What I did so far:
Let $f=a_{k}X^{k}+a_{k-1}X^{k-1}+...+a_{1}X+a_{0}$.
Then $(f^{2017})'=f^{n}\Leftrightarrow 2017\cdot f^{2016}\cdot f'=f^{n}$.
Hence, we obtain that $(a_{k}X^{k}+...+a_{0})^{n}\cdot \left [  2017\cdot (a_{k}X^{k}+...+a_{0})^{2016-n}\cdot (ka_{k}X^{k-1}+...+a_{1})-1\right ]=0$.
Additionally, for $x:=0$, we find that $2017\cdot a_{0}^{2016}\cdot a_{1}=a_{0}^{n}$.

Comment: Is $f^n(x) = (f(n))^x$ or $f^n(x) = \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)$?

Comment: It's $(f(x))^n$.

Comment: @flawr Most would write that $f^{(n)}(x)$. Then again, $f^n$ might also what many write as $f^{\circ n}$ for clarity ...

Comment: Please consider using some non-TeX in titles.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I personally don't think there's anything wrong with *some* TeX being in a title. Some folks don't like that because TeX is harder to index than is pure text. When a title is *all* TeX, though, I think that's an issue. For example, when I click on a title that is all TeX, the title magnifies rather than taking me to the question. Thus, it makes navigation difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beginning from $2017f^{2016}f'=f^n$, we find that $2016\deg f+\deg f-1=n\deg f$, so $(2017-n)\deg f = 1$. This is only possible if $\deg f=1$ and $n=2016$.
So $f(x)=ax+b$ with $a\ne 0$. The the equation becomes $2017 a f^{2016}=f^{2016}$, so $a=\frac1{2017}$ and $b$ is arbitrary.